# Plugins Select option with search not working on appended option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, selectize.js, tom-select

Does anyone know how to use select option with search but the option is appended. the plugins that I've tried cant read the appended option. Does anyone know how? Please help. thanks.
Plugins i've tried are tom-select / seletize / chosen.

```js
    const mealOrder = document.getElementById("orderMeal")

    mealOrder.addEventListener('change', function(){
      switch (this.value) {
      
        case "1":
             $("#appendOption").empty();
            $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>`+
                              `<option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>`+
                              `<option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>`);
          break;
          
        case "2":
           $("#appendOption").empty();
            $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Pizza, Popcorn, Burger</option>`+
                              `<option>Burger, Chicken Wings, Soda</option>`+
                              `<option>Random</option>`);
          break;
          
        case "3":
             $("#appendOption").empty();
             $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Soup. Carbonara, Coke</option>`+
                              `<option>Chocolate Cheese Cake, Coffee</option>`+
                              `<option>Random</option>`);
          break;
           case "0":
             $("#appendOption").empty();
             $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Select</option>`);
             break;
      }
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="chooseSomething" id="orderMeal">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Combo Meal 1</option>
            <option value="2">Combo Meal 2</option>
            <option value="3">Combo Meal 3</option>
     </select>
     <select id="appendOption">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to destroy and re-initialize the TomSelect to have the `select` updated.

Ps: Alternatives to this approach, [TomSelect API Docs](https://tom-select.js.org/docs/api/) offers various options. You can use `removeItem()` function instead, then add them back based on the condition. In my humble opinion, I think this is a better approach than the way you're currently clear/append the `option` tags

```js
const mealOrder = document.getElementById("orderMeal")

// Initialize TomSelect and refer the instance to a variable
let mealTomSelect = new TomSelect("#appendOption", {
  sortField: {
    field: "text",
    direction: "asc"
  }
});

mealOrder.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // you have to destroy the TomSelect instance first
  mealTomSelect.destroy();

  switch (this.value) {
    case "1":
      $("#appendOption").empty();
      $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>` +
        `<option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>` +
        `<option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>`);
      break;

    case "2":
      $("#appendOption").empty();
      $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Pizza, Popcorn, Burger</option>` +
        `<option>Burger, Chicken Wings, Soda</option>` +
        `<option>Random</option>`);
      break;

    case "3":
      $("#appendOption").empty();
      $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Soup. Carbonara, Coke</option>` +
        `<option>Chocolate Cheese Cake, Coffee</option>` +
        `<option>Random</option>`);
      break;
    case "0":
      $("#appendOption").empty();
      $("#appendOption").append(`<option>Select</option>`);
      break;
  }

  // Then re-initialize it
  mealTomSelect = new TomSelect("#appendOption", {
    sortField: {
      field: "text",
      direction: "asc"
    }
  });

})
```

```css
.ts-wrapper .ts-control .item {
  color: red;
}

.ts-wrapper .ts-dropdown .option {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.2.1/dist/css/tom-select.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.2.1/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>
<select class="chooseSomething" id="orderMeal">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Combo Meal 1</option>
  <option value="2">Combo Meal 2</option>
  <option value="3">Combo Meal 3</option>
</select>
<select id="appendOption">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! 

follow up question (By any change) -  do you know how can I customize the style of tom-select? like changing the font-size and height.

Comment: I updated my answer to add the css section to modify the select. You have to inspect to the page using Chrome Inspect Devtool, get the class name then write the css rule for them.  Can you mark my answer as correct? Glad I can help :).